# Development Environment for Jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax, development-environment

What develepment environment do you use when you need to work on javascript?What options have as an Asp.net developer for working with javascript or jQuery in order to have possibilities to test,develop in realtime?
I tried to set up the intellisense to make it work the jQuery documentation, but that's not working.
Right now i'm using Firebug to test my scripts and also editing there,but for example i would like to view the markup and the console together but that's not possible on FireBug.
i don't think that's the best solution for that kind of work.
If you have any ideea how to solve my problem or do you have a suggestion please post it here.

Thanks!

**Update**
[JSBin](http://jsbin.com) 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) are nice alternatives too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try Aptana. 
It's free, it's awesome, and comes with JQuery & Prototype built-in.
It also has screencasts.

Comment: This is a very cool prog,on startup you can choose all the javascript library to set up the intellisense.For me it's not the ideal tool for develepment.Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 6):

The essentials.

1. Your favorite text editor.  That's [vim](http://www.vim.org/) for me.
2. [Google](http://www.google.com)
3. [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com)
4. [Web Developer's Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60)
5. Two monitors (solves your whole "can't view source and the console together" problem)

Comment: 5.
Yeah,it would be nice to have a second monitor.But in that case you have two browsers opened with the same source.(I try that also :P )And for me sometimes it flickers,especially if modify some html source.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Komodo Edit](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/). I think you can attach jQuery to it (I use it for PHP primarily).

Update: Just found out it already has jQuery support built-in.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something to look at, although it won't solve all your problems, Steve Yegge was working on a new [javascript mode for emacs](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/03/js2-mode-new-javascript-mode-for-emacs.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can debug JavaScript with Visual Studio 2008: 
[Visual Studio 2008 JavaScript Debugging - basic guide](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/19/vs-2008-javascript-debugging.aspx)

There was a fix for JQuery/JavaScript intellisense to make it better: 
[Intellisense Hot fix for VS 2008](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx)

Comment: I tried this and in a test project works very well,but in our project this is not working and i don't put more time to investigate this.

Answer (score 1):

I just use what ever is on hand. Dragonfly in Opera, Firebug in FF, IEtester has it's own thing but I never use it.

As for editing, I'm on the basics and only use Notepad++

If I were you though, I would sit down and try to solve a problem in a few tools before choosing what you like the most.

Comment: I tried Firebug on FireFox on IE the IE debugger,also i have NotePad++,but i'm sure these tools are not simpliest way to develop 'on the fly' javascript code. :)